# Google Chart Visualization API, Bar chart values / tooltips

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to add the actual value of all the bars in my chart to the
end of each bar. I want this to either replace, or to add to the tool-
tip functionality.

I see that this is possible in the image chart, it is the
functionality described in the following link that I wish to
replicate:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#image_bar_chart

I am wondering if this is possible in the Javascript based version of
the bar chart?

Many thanks,

H.

Comment: That link you provided is the javascript version, so are you looking for anything else?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift response and sorry if my information wasn't clear. The link I provided builds a png image using Javascript, however, there is also another way to create charts using only Javascript. That version can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#bar_chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's no built in functions to draw text ad-hoc on top of google's different charts.  Behind the scenes, it's generating SVG so you could try to insert some valid SVG on your own.

Another option would be to use a more flexible (but less featureful) library like raphael.js:

http://raphaeljs.com/